# not able to see cron job logs in a dedicated file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I am new to Linux and its commands and I am trying to learn cron jobs. So, I created a cronjob that runs every minute.

```
* * * * * /home/vscoder/script.sh >> /var/log/cronjob.log 2>&1
```

I know that by default in Ubuntu cron job logs are stored in /var/log/syslog file but I am trying to save logs for my cron job in /var/log/cronjob.log file.
But my cron logs are not stored in it, cronjob.log file is empty. Please refer below:

```
vscoder@vscoder-VirtualBox:/var/log$ cat cronjob.log
vscoder@vscoder-VirtualBox:/var/log$
```

What should I do so that my cron job logs will be stored in /var/log/cronjob.log file.

Comment: Is `/var/log/cronjob.log` writable by the user?  You might want to choose a different location.

Comment: Hi @TobySpeight, thanks for your comment. I tried different directory /home/vscoder/cronjobs.log file and it worked. I think files stored in /var/log are not writable by user.